# How to delete a MySQL database in java selected record (row)

Tags: java, mysql

How to delete a MySQL database selected record (row)
I use this code

```
connectDB();
try{
    java.sql.PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM tbl_codes WHERE No=? ");
    String sql = "Delete FROM user WHERE No= "+txt_search_code.getText(); 
    pstmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
    pstmt.setString(1,txt_search_code.getText());
    pstmt.execute();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, " Your new records Deleted Succsessfully!!");   
} catch(Exception e){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);
}
closeDB();
```

but it get an error like this -

> java.sql.SQLException:Parameter index out of range(1>number of
>   parameters,which is 0)

So how can I fix this probleam....(Examples please)
Thanks

Comment: Remove your String sql. You've already had stmt. Use it to execute query instead of pstmt

Comment: I tried this code  [ string sql = "Delete FROM user WHERE No= '" + txt_search_code.getText()+ "'"; ]

but it still get an error like this -

"java.sql.SQLException:Parameter index out of range(1>number of parameters,which is 0)"

So how can I fix this probleam....(Examples please)
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
connectDB();
try{
    java.sql.PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM tbl_codes WHERE No=? ");
    stmt.setString(1,txt_search_code.getText());
    stmt.execute();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, " Your new records Deleted Succsessfully!!");   
} catch(Exception e){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);
}
closeDB();
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are not using quotation marks around the string you want to delete.

It should be the following:

```
string sql = "Delete FROM user WHERE No= '" + txt_search_code.getText()+ "'";
```

Sql is now tring to convert to numerics.

Comment: Excuse me, that is definitely better!